# How do I change the size of a space in VSCode?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, visual-studio-code

VSCode Version: 1.41.1
OS Version: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

In my VS Code, the space is only half the size of one character.
How do I change the size of a space to one character?

[image]

Comment: Use a monospace font is probably the only way.

Comment: Your comments were very helpful.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of the space (or any other character) is determined by the font, not VS Code.

I personally love Fira Code, but you can choose any monospace font. I found [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20190806234521/https://speckyboy.com/best-free-fonts-coding/), which shows a couple of good ones that will all give you want you need.

There is also a pre-installed monospace font in Ubuntu, which I think is called Ubuntu Monospace.

To set it in VS Code, press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the search box, select *Preferences: Open Settings (UI)*, and search for Font Family. Set that to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem was solved.
I will refer to the list of fonts you gave me.
Thank you very much!